# Pythonic way of creating a class in python 2.7.6

Tags: function, class, python-2.7, methods

I have defined a module to work with several types of data files (filetypes.py for example). In it I defined a base class to deal with file opening and some basic processing which is inherited by the remaining classes specific to each type of data file. In each of these classes I used the __init__() method to initialize some class variables and another method to read the data file that has as input the filename (this operation can not be done in the __init__() method). Something like:

```
class maintype(object):
    """main type class.""
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 1

class filetype1(maintype):
    """file type 1 class."""
    def __init__(self):
        self.b = 1

    def readfile(self, filename):
        self.ifile = open(filename, 'rb')
```

When calling this module from the main code, it feels a litle unnatural:

```
import filetypes

data = filetypes.filetype1()
data.readfile('some_file_name')
```

Question: wouldn't it be more pythonic to define in the module a function that returns the class instead of using the class method? Something like:

```
def file_type1(filename):
    class1 = filetype1()
    class1.readfile(filename)
    return class1
```

Now, it would look like:

```
import filetypes

data = filetypes.file_type1('some_file_name')
```

I have searched the web and couldn't find any helpful indications...

Comment: Before we worry about pythonic, you should first be aware that you're using incorrect [naming conventions](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) and terminology. `maintype` should be `MainType`, `readfile` should be `read_file`.  `readfile` is not a class method (it's an instance method), and the function `file_type1` is returning an instance of the class, not returning the class itself. As to the question, it is sometimes useful to define function that create an object and then call methods before returning the object. It is difficult to say whether this is appropriate for your use case.

Comment: You are right about the naming conventions and terminology, I am not at ease with them. Should I edit the question or leave it as it is?

Comment: Now that I have put my question into words I have been having second thoughts as to whether I am following the right path in the development of the module. I have put the focus on the different types of files and not on the data. What I am looking at is to a module that, independently from the type of file I am reading, I always get the same representation of the underlying data (I am working with sampled data coming from different types of sensors/systems). This other vision would make the design of the classes more streamlined.

Comment: See my edited answer, sorry for assuming you were a tard initially, remember to upvote and accept.

Answer (score 0):

No, `a=A()` where A is a class is the "pythonic" way, `__init__` is already a function.

If you extend a class but do not call the base-classes' `__init__`s you just get their functions, for example.

By the way, you can pass stuff to constructors.

eg:

```
class A(object):
     def __init__(self,extra):
          print("Look, extra: ",extra)
```

I dismissed the OP as a tard/noob who didn't really know what a constructor did, sorry for that, here's a better answer:

this is an object orientated thing, a function could do but you want that to belong somehow to your class, you could put them in the same python package, or a static method. If I had a complex number class, I'd make conjugate a static method because it belongs with complex numbers, however I'd put something that used complex numbers, but what not important to all complex numbers outside.

Suppose I had a `__str__`  function, obviously goes inside because every complex number can do this. Suppose I have a "input two numbers" function that prints out the complex number the user inputs, that is a function that happens to use complex numbers, therefore not a static method, or method.

Here's my example:

```
#! /usr/bin/python

class reading_thing_maybe(object):
    def __init__(self,filename=None):
        #usual constructor code
        print "\tConstructor!"

        if not filename is None:
            print "\tSpecial case, constructing but doing readfile right away!"
            self.readfile(filename)

    def readfile(self,filename):
        print "\tReding file:",filename

class other_reading_thing(object):
    def __init__(self):
        print "\tConstructor"

    def readfile(self,filename):
        print "\tReding file:",filename

    @staticmethod
    def read_from_file(filename):
        print "\tconstructing with a read from",filename
        result = other_reading_thing()
        result.readfile(filename)
        return result

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print "normal"
    a = reading_thing_maybe()
    print "assuming constructor takes nothing"
    b = reading_thing_maybe("hello")
    print "using the filename= format"
    c = reading_thing_maybe(filename="use me if constructor takes arguments")
    print "Static method"
    d = other_reading_thing.read_from_file("test")
```

Output:

```
alec@ATLaptop ~ $ chmod +x ./example.py 
alec@ATLaptop ~ $ ./example.py 
normal
    Constructor!
assuming constructor takes nothing
    Constructor!
    Special case, constructing but doing readfile right away!
    Reding file: hello
using the filename= format
    Constructor!
    Special case, constructing but doing readfile right away!
    Reding file: use me if constructor takes arguments
Static method
    constructing with a read from test
    Constructor
    Reding file: test
alec@ATLaptop ~ $
```

Comment: Like I mentioned in the question, putting the \__init__() method to read the file directly is not an option since there are other operations that have to be carried first (not shown in the example).

Comment: @pxc static method decorator to do it. You could also use named arguments. Something like `def __init__(self,filename=None):` then your constructor code, then `if not filename is None:` with `self.readfile(filename)` on the next line